# How close are current computer technologies in terms of energy efficiency to the Landauer Limit?

Tags: floating-point, history

I'm trying to figure out how close (in orders of magnitude) current computer technologies are in terms of energy efficiency to the Landauer Limit. However, I'm finding (seemingly) conflicting information about this, and the discrepancy seems to arise from different metrics and assumptions.

[This Royal Society piece](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2019.0061) (without a source) refers to a 1 attojoule/operation ($10^{-18}$ J) "six orders of magnitude smaller than today’s devices," which implies that we are **nine orders of magnitude** from the Landauer Limit.

[This Lesswrong article](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/N7KYWJPmyzB6bJSYT/the-next-ai-winter-will-be-due-to-energy-costs-1#comments) and [this graph](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Trendline-of-minimum-12CV-2-transistor-switching-energy-Values-were-calculated-using-the_fig3_4140106) (full text downloadable [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4140106_Approaching_the_physical_limits_of_computing/download)) analyze transistor switching energies and come up with a figure of **three orders of magnitude**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koomey%27s_law#Slowing_and_end_of_Koomey%27s_law), which cites [this blog](http://tikalon.com/blog/blog.php?article=2011/Landauer), claims that it is **six orders of magnitude** ("0.00001%"). I was able to verify the math the blog used, which based its calculations off of the 2012 RIKEN K Computer and used the assumption that 8.2 petaflops corresponded to $10^{20}$ bit operations (about $1.2 \cdot 10^4$ bit operations per floating point operation).

(1) Is there a widely accepted "standard" for the number of bit operations/transistor switches that correspond to each floating point operation, and does this number vary or change? I've heard numbers ranging anywhere from $10^4$ to $10^8$.

(2) What is the "correct" figure for the number of orders of magnitude that separates the energy efficiency current computer technologies from the Landauer Limit?